# How to Mount remote disc as local in Windows 7 and Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, network-share, mount, hard-drive

Is it possible to mount remote file system (on Windows 2003 server) as local disk in Windows 7?
I have Windows 2003 server with software RAID and some shares. On another computer with Windows 7 I have software which can access only data form local or USB disks.

This solution doesn't work because program doesn't see files in folder:
[Mount Remote CIFS/SMB Share as a Folder not a Drive Letter](https://serverfault.com/questions/105633/mount-remote-cifs-smb-share-as-a-folder-not-a-drive-letter)
Everything is the same LAN.

Answer (score 2):

The methods to mount a remotely-connected disk as a "local" disk, in Windows, basically boil down to using a SAN-style method of mounting the disk as a local block device. One method, for example, would be to use an iSCSI target on the server computer to export the disk (or a file on the disk) as an iSCSI block device, then use the built-in iSCSI initiator in Windows 7 to mount the exported block device.

If your application really expects a local disk then a block device mount method is pretty well your only option.