# Assigning more than 26 network drives on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

It looks like Windows 7 only allows for 26 network drives (`A:\` to `Z:\`, roughly).

Is there any way to get more?

Comment: If you need more that 26 drive letters, you're probably doing something wrong. Why do you need that many drive letters?

Comment: @longneck *you're probably doing something wrong* I don't doubt it.  Say my local network has over 26 computers, I copy files around between them. I don't want to RDP into each computer - using network drives is a little easier.  Is there an even easier solution than setting up 26+ mapped network drives?

Comment: `Say my local network has over 26 computers, I copy files around between them. I don't want to RDP into each computer - using network drives is a little easier. Is there an even easier solution than setting up 26+ mapped network drives?` - Yes, set up a central file server.

Comment: If you're copying files between computers you can use powershell to automate this process, or just use a central file share.

Comment: @SteamerJ Granted, PowerShell is very useful for this kind of thing - but sometimes Windows Explorer is the path of least resistance for infrequent tasks.

Comment: you wouldn't write it each time you do a copy, you'd write a function that either predefines the computers your copying to, or pulls in a txt file that has the list. Then you'd have parameters for source and destination of the file and it would just push it out to the destination on each of the computers in the list. That way you can just keep calling the same function each time you need to do this task and supply what you're pushing out and where it's going. I live by the motto if you have to do the same task twice or more, it gets a script so it can be automated.

Comment: Learn to use UNC's

Answer (score 1):

DFS Namespaces is probably what you'll want to look it. It will allow you to aggregate drive shares into a single namespace.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-namespaces/dfs-overview

Answer (score 1):

Just mount the remove shares [as subdirectories](https://serverfault.com/questions/105633/mount-remote-cifs-smb-share-as-a-folder-not-a-drive-letter?rq=1), instead of top-level drive letters. There's no limit on subdirectories.